# Base and height of a triangle is constant, what affects how many same squares I can fit inside it?

Tags: geometry, triangles

I've been wondering this for a while now.

If the base and height of a triangle is constant, what variables affect how many same squares I can fit inside a triangle without them overlapping each other?

I think the highest amount of squares can be fit if the triangle is a right triangle and the least if the triangle is obtuse.

**But if the triangle is acute, does the amount of same squares I can fit inside it get affected by the angles of the triangle or subsequently its shape?**

I have tried illustrating this but I couldn't draw precise lines, and I don't really need a formal proof if there even is any, so an illustration alone would be more than adequate and appreciated.

Comment: "what variables affect how many same squares I can fit inside a triangle without them overlapping each other?"  Same squares of what dimension?  Query is ambiguous.  Do you instead intend to ask the size of the largest single square that will fit in the triangle?  Alternatively,do you instead intend to ask: if you have a square of fixed dimensions, what controls which shape of the triangle, with fixed base and height, can accommodate the largest number of such squares, without any overlap?

Comment: Do you want position of top vertex for maximum location of squares?I mean the only parameter change is top vertex position (the one the altitude is drop from).

Comment: Sorry about not being specific, I am talking about a 2 dimensional space. ABC is a triangle with the base a and height h, "a" and "h" are constant values, in what way does the number of "whole squares" I can fit inside a triangle change when changing the shape of the triangle

Answer (score 3):

You can put just as many squares in an acute triangle as in a right triangle.  The width of the triangle a given distance above the base is a constant once you have the base and altitude.  In the triangles below, the base is $3$ and the width one unit above the base is $\frac {12}5$.  In the bottom row you can fit the width of the triangle one unit above the base rounded down, so you can fit $\lfloor \frac {12}5 \rfloor=2$ triangles.  In the next row you can fit the width of the triangle two units above the base rounded down.  Here that is $\frac 95$, so you can fit $1$.  In the third row you can fit $\frac 65$ rounded down, which is again $1$.  This works for all acute and right triangles.  The reason it fails for obtuse triangles is that the width one unit above is not over part of the base.  You have to take the overlap and round it down, which may give a smaller result.

[image]

Comment: based on your drawing, it seems that it may be unclear.  Suppose that you had squares that had dimensions of (3/4) (on each side) as the squares portrayed in your picture.  It seems that the right triangle would accommodate an extra square, where the acute triangle would not.  In fact, if my assertion is true, it will (in general) be true precisely because (in your examples) the right triangle has **wasted space** on the right side only, while the acute triangle has wasted space on the left side and the right side.  ...see next comment

Comment: This intuition suggests that (depending on the square's dimensions), the right triangle is never inferior re housing squares, and is sometime superior.

Comment: No.  The width $\frac 34$ above the base is the same in both, $3 -\frac 35 \cdot \frac 34=\frac {51}{20}$.  You can fit three $\frac 34$ squares in the bottom row of either triangle.  Drop verticals to the base from the points on the sides $\frac 34$ up.  That is the region you put the squares in and it is the same on both triangles.  Check it for a square of side $\frac{15}{23}$.  You should get exactly four squares in the bottom row for both triangles.

Comment: +1: Oh! It just hit me.  Regardless of the size of the square, the limiting factor will be the width of the triangle at the **top** of the row that the squares are being placed on.  And as you have indicated, this width must be identical for each triangle, regardless of the acute angles used to construct the triangle.  Very elegant.

Comment: I agree with this answer provided the squares are restricted to being aligned with the specified base of the triangle. It may be that aligning the squares with another side works better in some cases.

Comment: I never thought about not aligning the squares with the base of the triangle, I guess the best method from here on out would be to use an AI to place pre-determined sized squares inside the triangles in the most optimized way and analize the results

Comment: General packing problems are hard.  Here if we specify aligned squares it is obvious what the best configuration is and we just have to count them.  When the configurations are more general it becomes hard to figure out which is best.  They often are not symmetric at all.  You can go to packomania.com to see, though most of that is packing circles.